# Tokenize a detokenized newcommand - NEWCOMMAND/DETOKENIZE Conflict

Tags: detokenize

The problem is very simple to understand. I have 2 folders:

- document.tex
- abc.tex (this file needs to be unchanged, which means, \detokenize must be a part of it)

**document.tex:**

```
\documentclass{article}


   \newcommand{\test}{3}
    
   \begin{document}
    
   1 + 2 = \test
    
   \input{abc}
    
   \end{document}
```

**abc.tex:**

```
\detokenize{1 + 2 = \test}
```

compiling document.tex gives us:

[image]

The problem here is, that because abc.tex contains \detokenize, the command \test will not be executed. I dont want to delete \detokenize in the abc.tex file, it has to stay there. Is there any way around to "tokenize" the abc.tex file?

Comment: `\begingroup \let\detokenize\relax \input{abc} \endgroup`?

Comment: works perfect thx! @UlrikeFischer the final problem i have, is in my latest post in the question segment. I used exactly what you suggested, but have another final problem. Can you take a look please?

Comment: why do you want detokenize here, it is very odd to input a detokenzed  string like this